# Magazine auto-publish by date & month

Tags: 7, nodes

I am developing a complex website which will serve as an online magazine.

I am currently experimenting with the Book module and organizing my content in months but I am not sure it is a long term solution.

**I am trying to achieve a setup which at midnight of February 28th will automatically publish all content associated will the new month of March and un-publish content for the previous month.**

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions to achieve this.

Comment: Use Rules module for this kind of feature.

Comment: I've removed that last part of this question that you edited in as it's more of a second question. Please feel free to add it as another question :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend the [Scheduler](http://drupal.org/project/scheduler) module.

From the module page:
"This module allows nodes to be published and unpublished on specified dates."

I have used it with custom content types without an issue, so I imagine it should work with Book if you like how that module works.

Just note, it publishes/unpublishes on cron runs, so either set your cron to run exactly at midnight every day (preferred), or in your system settings (/admin/config/system/cron) have cron run every hour.  If you have drupal execute cron be aware that it will not actually run every hour, but rather the next time you have a visitor.

Comment: Thanks this sounds great. I tried it immediately but I wonder if you know  if I can somehow select a month and a year for publishing/unpublishing rather than type in dates?

Comment: I believe it will use the date_popup module if you have that installed

Answer (score 1):

You can use cron to achieve this,

- Use hook cron in your custom module and write the codes to publish and unpublish based on your conditions
- You can use [Elysia Cron](http://drupal.org/project/elysia_cron) to schedule this cron job to run in every month or every first day of a month. Or you can configure cron in your server to set exact timings.

Comment: Thanks but do you think the book module is the best solution or is there something better?